# How to use for loop to insert row into QSqltablemodel from a list?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, for-loop, qsqltablemodel

Below is the Database model:

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('book.db')
db.open()

self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
self.model.setTable("card")
self.model.select()
```

For example:

```
a = "name"
b = 30
c = "M"
data_row = [a, b, c]

r = self.model.record()
r.setValue("name", "name")
r.setValue("age", 30)
r.setValue("gender", "M")
self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
self.model.select()
```

The database have 3 columns that are 'name', 'age','gender'.

My question is how to insert row in to Sqlite table using QSqlTableModel using with for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried below code That's worked for me :
Used "for-loop" to count-columns and zip() Function for Parallel Iteration.

```
a = "name"
b = 30
c = "M"
data_row = [a, b, c]

columns = []
for col in range(self.model.columnCount()):
    columns.append(col)

r = self.model.record()
for col, rec in zip(columns, data_row):
    r.setValue(col, rec)

self.model.insertRecord(-1, r)
self.model.select()
```

Comment: Strangely enough, this is marked as working, so I believe it is. However `columnCount()` is not in the `QSqlTableColumn` documentation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html).